# Set apart project images from project and design model in Django

Tags: django, model

I have a project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
     category = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectCategory)
     designer = models.ForeignKey(User)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     description = models.TextField()
     image1 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     image2 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     image3 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
```

I want to set apart images to another model:

```
class ProjectImages(models.Model):
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
     image1 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     image2 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     image3 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
```

Is this a right model? Or what is the right way to set apart project images from project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want `OneToOne` relationship rather than `Forienkey`, so the model can be

```
class ProjectImages(models.Model):
     project = models.OneToOneField(Project)
     image1 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     image2 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     image3 = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
```

This is good if number of images per project is fixed to 3 (or a number you decide).

---

If you want variable number of images you can create a model as

```
class ProjectImages(models.Model):
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
     image = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
     sequence_num = IntegerField()
```

You can add as many `ProjectImages` you want and specify `sequence_num` to them (if required).

Answer (score 1):

One image field is OK. You can save lots of images in each project.

```
class ProjectImages(models.Model):
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
     image = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the flexibility of 0 to N images per project, then you should use the following ProjectImage model:

```
class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='.../designs/')
```